# "QueryFailedError: operator does not exist", How to use PostgreSql array contains operator with typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am using TypeOrm with TypeScript and I have a `products` table like this.

```
export enum ColorTone {
  Cambridge = 'GREY_TONE',
  Nicolock = 'RED_TONE',
  Keystone = 'BLUE_TONE',
  TechoBloc = 'YELLOW_TONE',
}

@Entity('product')
export class Product {
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: Brand,
    array: true,
    default: [],
  })
  colorTones: ColorTone[]; // available colors for a product
}
```

I want to find all products containing a specific color tone available.
I tried this using TypeOrm query.

```
...
constructor(@InjectRepository(Product) private productsRepository: Repository<Product>) {}
...

findProducts(colorTone: ColorTone): Promise<Product[]> {
  return this.productsRepository.createQueryBuilder('product')
    .where('product.colorTones @> ARRAY[:colorTone]', { colorTone });
}
```

But I get this console error.

```
QueryFailedError: operator does not exist: product_colortones_enum[] @> text[]
...
```

Not sure if there is a way to do the typecasting.

I tried to find the solution all day and any relevant link or reference link will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast to the correct type.

```
.where('product.colorTones @> ARRAY[:colorTone::product_colortones_enum]', { colorTone });
```

If typeorm gets confused by the colon salad, move the cast to the array

```
.where('product.colorTones @> ARRAY[:colorTone]::product_colortones_enum[]', { colorTone });
```

Comment: That's awesome. It works. Thank you, man.